# Left shift some bits into a existing number

Tags: c#, .net, bit, bit-shift

I have the following existing integer number:

128  = 1000.0000

And I want to shift the following integer number by 2 positions to the left ...

15 = 0000.1111

... into the existing number to bitindex 6:

`MyResult` should be = 1011.1100 = 188

I've tried this, but the result is wrong. Also if I change the `positionsToShift`  to 2:

```
int existingNumber = 128;
int numberToLeftShift = 15;
int positionsToShift = 6;

int myResult = (existingNumber << positionsToShift) | numberToLeftShift;
```

Comment: Typo? `var myResult = (numberToLeftShift << positionsToShift) | existingNumber;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your explanations you want `numberToLeftShift` to shift

```
  15 << 2
```

anf then combine with *existing integer number*:

```
  (15 << 2) | 128
```

Implementation

```
  int existingNumber = 128;
  int numberToLeftShift = 15;
  int positionsToShift = 2;   // we want shift by 2 to the left; not by 6

  // numberToLeftShift and existingNumber are swapped
  int myResult = (numberToLeftShift << positionsToShift) | existingNumber;
```

Comment: It is worth noting to the OP that if you wanted to use the number 3 and put it in at position 6  then you would need to modify this logic to work out how much shift is needed. Given its not clear whether numbers other than 15 will ever be used though then this may not be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

According to your textual description, you should use

```
var myResult = (numberToLeftShift << positionsToShift) | existingNumber;
```